# Why are files enqueued with wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script 404 Not Found?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

[image]
code script

[image]
Error net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Scrips Not Loaded

Comment: Please share js and css files screenshots or share the code of these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to load files from the assets folder, but you made a typo and named the folder assests and didn't notice

Comment: change it but still got this http://localhost/Ebridge_W/wp-content/plugins/SecondE/include/assests/mystyle11.css?ver=5.3.4net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Thank you.File Loaded